# Docker MongoDB image doesn't run scripts in docker-entrypoint-initdb.d when entrypoint is supplied

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I want to use Mongo with transactions so I am trying to set up a replica set (containing only one Mongo node) with docker.

I want to automatically run `rs.initiate()` once my database starts up. To do this, I'm using a script in docker-entrypoint-initdb.d.

I also need to start the mongo node with the replSet option, so I updated the entrypoint value. When the entrypoint is my new command, the scripts I have in `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` does not run. When I comment out my new entrypoint, the scripts do run.

I know I could wrap my `docker-compose up` command and a `docker-exec ... 'rs.initiate()'` command together in a script and call that instead of `docker-compose`, but that feels like a hack.

How can I make a Mongo node with a replSet and run `rs.initiate()`?

`docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  order-db:
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: mongo
    # entrypoint: ["mongod", "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet", "order"]
    volumes:
      - ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
      - ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/run.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/run.sh:ro
      - ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/arun.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/arun.sh:ro
```

`docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js`:

```
rs.initiate();
db.createCollection("just-testing-to-see-if-this-file-runs");
```

`docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/a-run.sh`:

```
echo "running aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
```

`docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/run.sh`:

```
echo "running!!!!!!!!"
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution

Remove your `entrypoint` and set your `command` to `["--bind_ip_all", "--replSet", "order"]`

#### Problem

You're overwriting the entrypoint of the `mongo` image.  I'm not sure how you are expecting those startup scripts to run, but it's part of the [entrypoint file](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh#L382-L389) that comes baked into the mongo image.  By defining your own entrypoint, you are preventing the container from executing the existing one, which is why those initialization scripts are not run.  Instead you can define your additional `mongod` arguments as part of the `command` which will then be passed into the entrypoint.  Then the entrypoint will pass them to the mongod call.  You can see [here](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh#L5) and [here](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh#L416) how the entrypoint handles taking additional arguments and passing them through to `mongod`.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that this approach creates a regular node first, and then recreates it in the replica set?

I get the error that `This node was not started with the replSet option` when my `mongo-init.js` runs, and then a message that the server was restarted, and then a message that I need to initialize the replica set.

Comment: Np.  Yes you're right about the way the entrypoint works.  A mongo instance is [started](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh#L338), then the init scripts are run, then it is [stopped](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh#L391).  Then later it starts up mongo again with your arguments.  You need to run `rs.Initialize()` after the db is up, not during the init.  To do this use `--eval` instead of an init script, see [here](https://www.sohamkamani.com/docker/mongo-replica-set/#using-docker-compose).